# Cannot read property 'length' of null in script

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm trying to call a function from code behind in script. That function i just returning list of employee
i'm just trying not to use grid view.
I just copy the code in at the same project and changes the names of function and the name inside the colModel: [] 
here's my script:

```
function loadMoretha60grid() {
    $('#timesheetgrid').jqGrid("GridUnload");
    getmoreThan60(function (data) { loadTimesheetTableMoeretha60(data); });

}
function loadTimesheetTableMoeretha60(timelog) {
    var lastsel;
    var startpage = 1;
    $('#timesheetgrid').jqGrid({
        datatype: 'local',
        data: timelog,
        editurl: 'clientArray',
        colNames: ['CompanyID', 'EMPName', 'START_DATE', 'END_DATE',
            'TOTALHOURS'],

        colModel: [
            { name: 'CompanyID', index: 'CompanyID', editable: 'false', align: 'center', width: '150', sortable: false, },
            { name: 'EMPName', index: 'EMPName', editable: 'false', align: 'center', width: '275', resizable: false },
            { name: 'START_DATE', index: 'START_DATE', editable: 'false', align: 'center', width: '175', resizable: false },
             { name: 'END_DATE', index: 'END_DATE', editable: 'false', align: 'center', width: '175', resizable: false },
              { name: 'TOTALHOURS', index: 'TOTALHOURS', editable: 'false', align: 'center', width: '175', resizable: false },

        ],
        pager: '#timesheetgridpager',
        viewrecords: true,
        forceFit: false,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        width: '1000',
        emptyrecords: "No Record/s found",
        loadtext: "Loading",
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
        height: 'auto',
        caption: 'Timesheet Listing'

    });

    $('#timesheetgrid').jqGrid('navGrid', '#timesheetgridpager', {
        edit: false,
        save: false,
        add: false,
        cancel: false,
        del: false,
        search: false,
        refresh: false
    });
    $('#timesheetgrid').jqGrid('inlineNav', '#timesheetgridpager', {
        add: false,
        edit: false,
        save: false,
        cancel: false,
        restoreAfterSelect: false
    });
}
function getmoreThan60(callback) {

    var timelog = [],
        params = {
            name: $('#empnamebox').val(),
            dateStart: '2019-09-01',
            dateEnd: '2019-09-29'
        };
    showLoadingGif();
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: baseUrl + 'Timesheet.aspx/getMore60hrs',
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            timelog = data.d;
            hideLoadingGif();
            if (typeof callback != 'undefined')
                callback(timelog);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr, status, error);
            hideLoadingGif();
        }
    });


}
```

[image]

here's my method

```
  [WebMethod]
        public static void getMore60hrs(string name,string dateStart,string dateEnd) {
            TDKDataAccessLayer dataAcc = new TDKDataAccessLayer();
            List<morethan> records = new List<morethan>();
            dataAcc.DepartID = Convert.ToInt32(DeptID);
            dataAcc.Name = name;
            dataAcc.DateStart = dateStart;
            dataAcc.DateEnd = dateEnd;
           records = dataAcc.MoreThan60hrs();

        }
```

By the way 
I don't know what to do about this because i came from windows form c#

Comment: We need the section of jQuery that has the word `length` in it, it doesn't appear to be in the code you provided

Comment: you mean the jQuery Grid.min.js ? is that need to modified? because there's a code like my question on the same project but it is working fine

Comment: it's happening inside loadTimesheetTableMoeretha60() function, could you paste the whole script? Did you check timelog if it contains rows/columns?

Comment: If possible for you, try to click the jquery.jqGrid.min.js:101 in which that it throws error in that file in line 101
and it also means that some variable was being passed their and it was not accepted because it was null and that it cannot
tell the lenght property of it. Try tracing it.

Comment: Also, in webmethod, at `dataAcc.DepartID = Convert.ToInt32(DeptID);`, does DeptID have a value?

Comment: im sure that the DeptID has value ,

Comment: i try to alert the timelog is says null, nut on my method getMore60hrs the list has value

Comment: you have not return anything from the web method. try to set the return type from void to string, return something and see if you can alert something from the timelog. If yes, try returning the serialized records.

Comment: ahh yes i forgot to return the list and i chage my method from void to objuect, but now its not showing data, but there's rows

Comment: theres exact number of rows but its all blank

Comment: okey its showing now the problem is the colnames is supposed to be the as in the list result

Comment: One more think to consider - the last item in colModel ends with comma, which in some browsers may cause a problem. Remove that comma and tray (The TOTALHOURSE item)